# Best way to achieve finding all of the words that start with a "#" character in all rows of a column

Tags: ms-access

I'm not sure I'm asking the question right as I'm a newbie at access.  But I've imported an excel file that has a column of text and I need to find all of the words that start with a "#" and copy them to a new column.  So on my excel file on column C I have a few sentences that has anywhere from 2 words that have #word1 #word2 or 20 words that have "#" in front of the word.  In almost all of the cells the words starting with a # are spaced out but some are running into each other like #sky#is#blue   How I would like it to work is when it finds any of the words it creates a Word1, Word2, Word3 cell in a new column.  But if that is not possible I can create 30 columns prior.  What would be the best way to achieve this?  And is it possible to use a LIKE query to do this?

Comment: Create new table for #words, using VBA cycle thru rows in imported table, analyze each record and create new record in new table for each found word. Of course those records should have reference to the record in imported table.

Comment: A query can find all the records with # character: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE InStr([fieldname],"#")>0`. Splitting the string will require VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my opinion, is by using the `LIKE` operator. Note that `#` is a wildcard for any one number in the `LIKE` operator, so we need to bracket it.

Select all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Field1 LIKE "*[#]*"
```

Only the rows starting with `#`:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Field1 LIKE "[#]*"
```

Move those rows to a separate column:

```
UPDATE MyTable Set Field2 = Field1 WHERE Field1 LIKE "*[#]*"
```